# Windows 7 recent apps like android

Tags: windows-7

I really like the recent apps feature of Android 4.0, it shows 5 recent apps you can scroll through and get use that app.

Is it possible to get recent apps  in Windows 7 like that.

P.S. - I am not talking about "Recent Places" feature of Windows 7

[image]

Comment: Yeah, in your Start Menu, there is Recent Programs (immediately above the Search box).

Comment: Can't see [here](http://i39.tinypic.com/auwr9l.png).

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows Vista, but should be the same for Windows 7.

1. Right click on the Start Menu Taskbar
2. Choose Properties
3. Click on the Start Menu tab

You should see Privacy at the bottom of the window.

Select the `Store and display a list of recently opened programs`.

Comment: It stores a list of recently opened files...

Comment: If you open a program and then close it, it won't be visible unless you open a file using it...

Answer (score 0):

By default the Start Menu is set to display 10 most recently used programs. However it looks like you have pinned 10 programs to the Start Menu, thus leaving no space for any more to be added.

Just modify the settings highlighted below and increase the Start Menu size:

[image: 1]

Now you'll be able to see both pinned and recently used programs divided by a separator:

[image: 2]

Comment: I have the same settings, but it does not work as intended, I opend Window Media Player, closed it.., and then it was not in the list there.. I guess that list randomly displays newly installed programmes or most accessed ones...

Comment: What did you set the Start Menu size to?

Comment: Its 10, and I haven't pinned any program.

Comment: Are you *sure* you haven't pinned any? Can you right-click the ones shown above and see if there's an option to unpin them? Otherwise try removing all of them, empty the Start Menu and run some program. Final option, refer to my screenshot above, uncheck *both* options under **Privacy** and OK your way out. This should clear the Start Menu and the recent list. Now go back and re-enable the two options, then run a program and see if it shows up in the Start Menu or not.

Comment: Ok.. I've tried it, its still not working, I have also uploaded a video for same, over [here](http://tinypic.com/r/6i8i8l/5)

Comment: Your video doesn't show a clean Start Menu like I suggested. Right-click each program currently displayed, select "Remove from this list". Once it's empty run a program and see. Also, try running the program directly instead of running a file that opens in the program.

Comment: If I try removing any program from a list, a new program automatically takes its place. I also tried opening applications both ways, using a file and directly as well.. But nothing works, isn't there any third party app for achieving something like this?

Comment: So did you even bother to try what I mentioned [above](http://superuser.com/questions/605886/windows-7-recent-apps-like-android/606141?noredirect=1#comment749466_606141) to [clear your Start Menu](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/clear-lists-on-the-start-menu-and-taskbar) (unchecking the two Privacy options, applying, then re-checking and applying)? This will clear your Start Menu *completely*, and anything you run after that should show up.

Comment: Yes, I tried, but it does not work as intended, my start menu clears up, but as I open, say Windows Media Player, it does not show up in Start Menu...

Comment: Okay, so here is what I noticed, only the programs fired using Strat Menu shows up there in list...

Comment: That restriction might well be the case. I personally don't use the feature at all.